# Why does collections module not have custom set or tuple functions?

Tags: python

The collections module has functions like

```
UserDict
UserList
UserString
```

which are used to create a custom dictionary or list or string.

One example could be to create a custom dictionary, which does not support item deletion.

But why is there no,

```
UserSet
UserTuple
```

???

Comment: The three types exist for historical reasons back when subclassing of builtins wasn't possible. There is little point having them today, and even less point adding more.

Comment: Questions of the form "Why does library __________ not implement ____________?" are generally unanswerable by anyone other than the author(s) of the library. People can speculate, but that is somewhat opinion-based.